Density of $H^2$ ball in the unit ball of $H^1$
Is there a number $R>0$ such that ball
$$\{v \in H^2(\Omega) \mid \lVert v \rVert_{H^2(\Omega)} < R\}$$
is dense in the $H^1$ unit ball
$$\{u \in H^1(\Omega) \mid \lVert u \rVert_{H^1(\Omega)} < 1\}?$$
$H^2$ is dense in $H^1$, so one might expect this property. Here $\Omega$ is a bounded Lipschitz domain.

Closed balls in Hilbert $H$ (more generally, reflexive Banach) spaces are weakly compact and hence closed in every Banach space which contains $H$ (with a continuous embedding).

Let us define
$$
B := \{ v \in H^1(\Omega) \mid v \in H^2(\Omega), \|v\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \le R \}
$$
for some fixed constant $R > 0$. Interestingly, $B$ is a closed subset of $H^1(\Omega)$.
Indeed, let a sequence $(v_k) \subset B$ be given such that $v_k \to v$ in $H^1(\Omega)$. Since the $H^2$ norm of $(v_k)$ is bounded, we can extract a subsequence (without relabeling) such that $v_k \rightharpoonup w$ in $H^2(\Omega)$.
Since $H^2(\Omega)$ is continuously embedded in $H^1(\Omega)$, we get $v = w$. Finally, the weak lower semicontinuity of the norm implies
$$
\|v\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \le \liminf_{k \to \infty} \| v_k \|_{H^2(\Omega)} \le R.$$
This shows $v \in B$.
Hence, your desired density cannot hold.
Note that the argument uses almost no special properties of the involved spaces and generalizes to many other situations.

I doubt so. Let us simplify the problem a little by considering the first derivative. $\Omega= (0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}^1$
$$H:= \{v \in H^1(\Omega) \mid \lVert v \rVert_{H^1(\Omega)} < R\}$$
and
$$L:=\{u \in L^2(\Omega) \mid \lVert u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} < 1\}?$$
Now, $L$ contains all sorts of discontinuous functions that cannot be approached by any sequence of functions in $H$ with a bounded derivative.

@RyszardSzwarc Why? The essential difficulty is the same. The problem is: given a bounded set with lower regularity, can it be densely approximated by a bounded set with higher regularity. The answer is no. You can change my argument to "$H^1$
contains all sorts of functions with discontinuous gradient that cannot be approached by any sequence of functions in $H^2$ with a bounded second derivative."
